# Zipping - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, memory, zip

I have this code to zip folders, but when I zip large folders (10GB), I got an error with memory. It works fine with folders around 1GB.

Probably some memory leak, but where in my code is the leak? How can I fix this?

Thanks.

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:572)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:203)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.resolve(UnixFileSystem.java:93)
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:207)
at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1056)
at Zipper.addDir(Zipper.java:27)
at Zipper.addDir(Zipper.java:32)
at Zipper.addDir(Zipper.java:32)
at Zipper.addDir(Zipper.java:32)
at Zipper.addDir(Zipper.java:32)
at Zipper.addDir(Zipper.java:32)
at Zipper.addDir(Zipper.java:32)
at Zipper.addDir(Zipper.java:32)
at Zipper.addDir(Zipper.java:32)
at Zipper.zipDir(Zipper.java:17)
at Schedule.runBackup(Schedule.java:128)
at Machine.runBackup(Machine.java:108)
at Person.main(Person.java:51)
```

This is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Zipper {

static void zipDir(String zipFileName, String dir) throws Exception {
    File dirObj = new File(dir);
    try {
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName));
        addDir(dirObj, out);
        out.close();    
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, e.getMessage() + ". Is settings.xml correct?");
    }
}

static void addDir(File dirObj, ZipOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    try {
        File[] files = dirObj.listFiles();
        byte[] tmpBuf = new byte[1024];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            try {
                if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    addDir(files[i], out);
                    continue;
                }
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getAbsolutePath().replace(File.separatorChar,'/')));
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(tmpBuf)) > 0) {
                    try {
                        out.write(tmpBuf, 0, len);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }   
                out.closeEntry();
                in.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's your jdk version? The reason I asked is there is a [JIRA](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;:YfiG?bug_id=4705373) on it in jdk 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, check the heap size, although you probably have it set high enough if 1GB is ok.
Considering you deal with 10GB of uncompressed data, do not forget about the limits of the zip format: 4GB max size of an archive (if you don't use zip64). I don't know if this has something to do with your case, but it might just do.

As a side note, always `close()` streams inside a `finally`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're leaking, there are plenty of tools for tracking that down (such as jmap + jhat).

However, your problem might not be a leak.  How big are your directories?  The exception occured in listFiles, so if you have a really large directory (or set of directories, since you are using recursive traversal), perhaps you just have too many files.  As @CoolBeans said, you might just need to adjust your heap space parameters.

Comment: Too much data shouldn't be a problem since he uses `FileOutputStream`, the stream is not being kept in memory. But maybe he has a humongous amount of files and somehow it just pops...

Comment: That's what I meant; I have edited my post in case anyone else is confused.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: For listFiles(), the size of the data doesn't matter, however the number of files does.  If you have lots of small files in a directory, this will trigger OOME regardless of their size, since listFiles() needs to build up an array of all the file names before returning it.